# Cannot create a membership badge

Tags: civimember

Recently, our civiCRM update and we are not able to create a membership badge anymore.  This is all that pops up under "Actions..."

Comment: Can you provide more details if you getting any error? what problem you facing?

Comment: And what version did you update from and to?